# Почему команда idn возвращает ошибку could not convert from ASCII to UTF-8?

Tags: linux, bash

Выполняю команду:
`echo "президент.рф" | idn`

Получаю ошибку: `idn: could not convert from ASCII to UTF-8`

Из-за чего она появляется и как исправить?

Comment: Кириллический алфавит не является частью ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "президент.рф"` генерирует не-ASCII-строку, если у вас используется UTF-8 в консоли.

Вызывайте idn следующим образом:

```
$ echo "домен.рф" | CHARSET=UTF-8 idn
xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте для вызова программы *idn* использовать локаль, использующую кодировку utf8:

```
$ echo "домен.рф" | LC_ALL=C.utf8 idn
xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai
```

посмотреть локаль, используемую по умолчанию:

```
$ locale
```

посмотреть все сгенерированные локали:

```
$ locale -a
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: к сожалению, «не помогло» — это слишком мало информации. дополните текст вопроса выводом всех трёх упоминаемых в моём ответе команд.